# Modelo em Keras para TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Estou aprendendo TensorFlow e estou tentando passar um modelo de Deep Learning em Keras para TensorFlow, entretanto, estou tendo dificuldades.

Modelo Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=9,input_dim=7))

model.add(Dense(units=15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=3,  activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit((np.array(training_data_x).reshape(-1,7)),( np.array(training_data_y).reshape(-1,3)), batch_size = 256,epochs= 3)

model.save_weights('model.h5')
model_json = model.to_json()
with open('model.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

Gostaria de um auxílio para passar esse código para TensorFlow, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você está usando o backend TensorFlow, seu código Keras está basicamente criando um gráfico TF. Você pode simplesmente capturar este gráfico como modelo TF.

Keras usa apenas um gráfico e uma sessão. Você pode acessar a sessão via: K.get_session (). O gráfico associado a ele seria então: K.get_session (). Graph.

E pronto.

Comment: Vlw Antonius!!!